# Buttons are disabled in a ScrollView - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a button in a view inside a view inside a ScrollView:

```
UIScrollView
-ContentView
--PhoneNumberView
---UIButton
```

If the scrolling ability of the ScrollView is disabled the button clicks normally. However, if the scrolling is enabled the button seems to be disabled.

This is how I sent the content size of the ScrollView:

```
var contentRect = CGRectZero;
for view in self.contentView.subviews {
     contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame)
}
scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
scrollView.contentSize.height = scrollView.contentSize.height+20
```

and I also set those properties

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
scrollView.exclusiveTouch = true
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = true
```

and I finally tried to create a subclass of UIScrollView and I ended up with this:

```
class myScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

but still the button is not active whenever there is any scrolling.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I have few questions as - 1. Why you are setting content size from code itself (haven't you designed the UI with auto layout). 2. Why are you changing the scrollView properties like exclusive touches and that, as if want to enable and disable the scrolling then the scrolling property is enough.

Comment: Its all about content size. Visible views on scrollview is not clickable due to wrong content size setting.

Comment: because i have a textView that might expand or shrink.

Comment: Better to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the color of the `ContentView` & `Scrollview`. I think you are setting wrong `contentsize`. And your `PhoneNumberView` is outside the `contentsize` height.

**EDIT**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the buttons are outside the contentview, what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: set the height of your contentview properly.

Comment: You are using autolayout?

Comment: calculate the height of your content view's and set that height as contetsize's height.

Comment: yes, exactly what i did is the following: i added a scrollview and pin to 0 from all sides with the superview then i added a content view inside the scrollview and pin it 0 from all sides with the scrollview then i sat equal widths and height between superview and contentview

Comment: may i request you edit your answer to show how to do it please?

Comment: Your contentview height maybe bigger if your content is bigger.

Comment: the only problem is that the content height is calculated when the view appears

Comment: Don't calculate there.

Comment: because i have a textview and the text of the textview is obtained from the server and i have no idea about the height of the textview until i receive the text. so it has a dynamic height

Comment: then create outlet for height constraint of the contentView from storyboard and change height constraint when contentview height is bigger than 568.

Comment: as per my image calculation I am saying.

Comment: thanks it works perfectly, the only problem is it scroll way under the last button i have. any reason why?

Comment: i am not getting you.

Comment: i want my scrolling to end just under my last element in the content view. after setting what you suggested it scroll even more than my last element

Comment: I think you have navigation bar above.

Comment: I have not subtract as I have created demo for you. so please check this at your end.

Comment: never mind i did it, you are the best man thank you very much. i really dont know how can i thank you. i've been suffering with this for a really long time.

Comment: Welcome brother. Anytime help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117692/discussion-between-ali-alebrahim-and-bhadresh-mulsaniya).

Answer (score 2):

By setting

```
scrollView.exclusiveTouch = true
```

you tell scrollView to handle touches exclusively, so touches won't reach its subviews, so set this property to `false`

This line of code

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = true
```

basically delays touches on scrollview subviews, if you want button to respond immediately then set this property to `false` too.

Comment: whenever i set scrollView.delaysContentTouches to false, the scrollview does not scroll

Answer (score 0):

Drag all subviews from ContentView to ScrollView. And hide the ContentView. Make sure ContentView(ContainerView of scrollView) should also be a subView of scrollView.

Ex:
UIScrollView
--PhoneNumberView
---UIButton
-ContentView(This view should be hide)

Comment: Please add 4-space indentation to format the view tree properly (as code block). Best regards

Comment: Ah, ok, this is another proper solution, thanks (I even didn't know that adding 2 spaces before a linebreak makes it work as `<br>` :)